# Images in Fixed background image website not being responsive

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently learning Bootstrap and about website responsiveness. In my website I am creating 8 `<div>` in total out of which 4 contain images and 4 contain textual contents and each `<div>` containing textual content is placed after each of the `<div>` containing the images. The  containing the images has been given the class name of 'sect', i.e. `<div class="sect">`. The CSS of this class is as follows:

```
.sect {
    height: 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Due to the `background-attachment: fixed` the image `<div>` remains fixed and the other div's slide over them. The responsiveness of the image is maintained for screen sizes > 745px. Below this screen the the image is no more responsive. I have tried media queries to solve this issue but it still remains.

Here is the HTML code of my sample site:

```css
    .sub-sect {
        height: auto;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        padding-top: 0px;
    }
    @media (min-width: 745px) {
        .sect {
            height: 100%;
            background-size: cover;
        }
    }
    .sect {
        height: 100%;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    
    .sectOne {
        
        background-image: url('../Images/beautiful_garden_3-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg');
        
    }
    
    .sectTwo {
        
        background-image: url('../Images/burning_poker_joker-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg');
    }
    
    .sectThree {
        
        background-image: url('../Images/the_dark_knight_rises-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg');
        
    }
    
    .sectFour {
        background-image: url('../Images/lion_14-wallpaper-1366x768.jpg');
    }
    
    @media (max-width:450px) {
        .sub-sect h2 {
            font-size: 17px;
            font-weight: 600;
        }
        .sub-sect p {
            font-size: 13px;
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                <div class="container-fluid transparent-nav">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsed-nav" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed Background</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsed-nav">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#about-us">About Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#contact-us">Contact Us</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            
            <div class="sect sectOne"></div>
            <div class="sub-sect"  id="home">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><h2>Home</h2></div></div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 custom-para">
                            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sect sectTwo"></div>
            <div class="sub-sect" id="services">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><h2>Services</h2></div></div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 custom-para">
                            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sect sectThree"></div>
            <div class="sub-sect" id="about-us">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><h2>About Us</h2></div></div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 custom-para">
                            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sect sectFour"></div>
            <div class="sub-sect" id="contact-us">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><h2>Contact Us</h2></div></div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 custom-para">
                            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

All the other files linked in this HTML document are from Bootstrap. How do I make these images responsive below the 745px screen size and avoid the width of the image being cropped.

THE IMAGE RESOLUTIONS ARE THE SAME 1920x1080 FOR ALL THE IMAGES.

Can anyone please suggest a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Handling responsive images can be daunting sometimes and you're going through the hard road here. One of the best approaches is to set the width of the images to either `max-width: 100%` or `width: 100%`. This way, the images will, respectively, stretch to their max width inside the container, or will fill the width of the container no matter what. More of this [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_images.asp)

By setting the width to 100%, the width will automatically change as the page width changes, making them responsive. For the height you have to add `height: auto` so it changes according to the width.

Bootstrap simplifies this by having a class `img-responsive'.

> The .img-responsive class applies display: block; and max-width: 100%; and height: auto; to the image

This will work on all screen sizes. If you have one of the main issues with responsive images, that is, the height of the containers are different, then simply use [MatchHeight.js](https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height)

**Note:** unless you specifically want the images to not be taken into consideration by screen readers and hinder your site's accessibility, you should add the images as an `<img> HTML` element rather than using css `background`